# Craft Commerce 2: Get products which are availableForPurchase

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I try to get all the products of a certain category which have availableForPurchase set to true.

```
{% set criteria = craft.products.type( 'weine' ).relatedTo( cat ).search( 'availableForPurchase:1' ).orderBy( 'reihenfolge' ) %}
```

I don't use variants, but I guess I need to check the availability for the default variant. Is this possible in the query?